# Spring boot, Spring security - authentication returns null after redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, vaadin

In my project im using spring boot, spring security and vaadin.

**Code:**

```
String username = ...
String password = ...
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
Authentication result = authManager.authenticate(request);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
```

**My AuthenticationManager:**

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = (String) auth.getPrincipal();
    String password = (String) auth.getCredentials();
    MyUserDetails user = userService.loadUser(username,password);
    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =u ser.getAuthorities();
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,username, authorities);
```

After any redirect *SecurityContextHolder.getContext()* loses its content and returns **null**. The only information I was able to find is that the context should be repopulated by spring automatically from session right after redirect, but somehow this won't happen in my case.

**Edit:** 
I tried to retrieve spring securty context directly from session.

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes)     RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) attr.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
```

I'm not sure if i did it correctly but *SecurityContextImpl* is **null**.